# scala lift, remove locale and time zone from Sign Up

Tags: scala, lift

Greetings

I have the following code:

```
package net_alchim31_vscaladoc2_www.model

import java.util.Locale
import java.util.Properties
import net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaImpl
import net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaFactory
import scala.xml.XML
import net.liftweb.http.S
import net.liftweb.util.FieldError
import net.liftweb.mapper.MappedPostalCode
import net.liftweb.mapper.MappedCountry
import net.liftweb.mapper.MappedTextarea
import net.liftweb.mapper.MegaProtoUser
import net.liftweb.mapper.MetaMegaProtoUser
import net.liftweb.common.{Box, Full, Empty, Failure}

/*
import _root_.net.liftweb.mapper._
import _root_.net.liftweb.util._
import _root_.net.liftweb.common._
*/
// TODO : Captcha integration (ReCaptcha)
// * http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/6188f67398414268/606b0480d7dde507?lnk=gst&q=recaptcha#606b0480d7dde507
// * http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/java.html
// * reCaptcha info for alchim31 https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/site?siteid=314371730

// TODO : GeoLocalisation of JdR player
// * http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

/**
* The singleton that has methods for accessing the database
*/
object User extends User with MetaMegaProtoUser[User] with ReCaptcha {
  override def dbTableName = "users" // define the DB table name
  override def screenWrap = Full(<lift:surround with="default" at="content">
                                   <lift:bind/>
                                 </lift:surround>)
  override def signupFields = fieldOrder //TODO append captcha

  // define the order fields will appear in forms and output
  //override def fieldOrder = List(firstName, lastName, email, locale, timezone, password)
  override def fieldOrder = List(firstName, lastName, email, password)

  // TODO comment this line out to require email validations
  override def skipEmailValidation = true

  override def validateSignup(user: User): List[FieldError] = validateCaptcha() ::: super.validateSignup(user)
  override def signupXhtml(user: User) = {
    (<form method="post" action={ S.uri }>
       <table>
         <tr><td colspan="2">{ S.??("sign.up") }</td></tr>
         { localForm(user, false) }
         <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>{ captchaXhtml() }</td></tr>
         <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><user:submit/></td></tr>
       </table>
     </form>)
  }

}

/**
* An O-R mapped "User" class that includes first name, last name, password and we add a "Personal Essay" to it
*/
class User extends MegaProtoUser[User] {
  def getSingleton = User // what's the "meta" server

// object country extends MappedCountry(this) {
// override def defaultValue = S.containerRequest.flatMap(_.locale).getOrElse(Locale.getDefault).getDisplayCountry
// }
// object postalCode extends MappedPostalCode(this, this.country)

}
```

from:
https://github.com/davidB/vscaladoc2_www/blob/master/src/main/scala/net_alchim31_vscaladoc2_www/model/User.scala

I want to remove the locale and time zone fields with:

**override def fieldOrder = List(firstName, lastName, email, password)**

but nothing happens

not that I'm doing wrong

can someone help me please

Comment: this is the solution: http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/2ff51496a3052b59

Answer (score 2):

You're overriding the wrong def - should be signupFields.

```
override def signupFields: List[FieldPointerType]= List(firstName, lastName, email, password)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would copy MetaMegaProtoUser and MegaProtoUser, create new traits, and make the "User" object and class extend the traits.

KK